# Camel kafka what's meant by maxPollRecords configuration

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

Lets say we get exchange as follows by executing following simple code. How does maxPollRecords configuration of kafkaEndpoint affects this. After executing following code echange will have only one message from kafka. Default value is for maxPollRecords is 500.

```
Exchange exchange = kafkaConsumer.receive(kafkaEndpoint, 100);//ConsumerTemplate kafkaConsumer;
```

When using kafka library it's clear because consumer.poll() will return like following

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
```

So records will have only 500 records within it. But when it comes to camel kafka what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `maxPollRecords` is the same, its the kafka option and it does what you can find on the documentation at both Apache Camel and Kafka.

On the other hand the APIs you use are different, the first API via the Camel ConsumerTemplate is for *single* exchange (aka message) consuming. So you get 1 message.

Typically in Camel you setup a route, such as the Camel Kafka example (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/README.adoc) where the route will poll max 500 messages by default according to the `maxPollRecords` option, and then route those 500 messages in Camel.